# How to correctly narrow a function parameter containing "an object key or a function"

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a generic type "get property using string key or callback" function and I've hit a wall getting TS to narrow my type parameter to a key of the containing object.

The function is as follows:

```
function get<T, V>(value: T, fn: (value: T) => V): V;
function get<T, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P): T[P];
function get<T, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P | ((value: T) => any)):
    typeof prop extends (o: any) => infer V ? V : T[P] {
    switch (typeof prop) {
        case 'function':
            return prop(value);
        case 'string':
            return value[prop]; // ERROR HERE
        default: throw new TypeError('Property getter must be string or function');
    }
}
```

And the compiler complains in the `string` branch - apparently `prop` gets narrowed not to `P`, but to `P & string`, which can't be used to here, because it implies trying to return `T[string]` where a `T[P]` is required.

Is there a way to specify this correctly, or do I just sigh and suppress the error?

Comment: the chosen solution has flaws. Can you check my answer. The biggest issue is with string assumption which is not consistent in the function type and body.

Comment: I’ll check, I accepted fairly quickly because it got the job done for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to double check

```
function get<T, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P | ((value: T) => any)):
    T[P] {
    switch (typeof prop) {
        case 'function':
            return prop(value);
        case 'string':
            return value[prop]; // ERROR HERE
        default: throw new TypeError('Property getter must be string or function');
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDwBUA0iBqAfABQBuAhgDYioBciuiwY9ZVN9WAlIgLyEEu9fAG4AUKEiwEKdNjwAFRKgAeUVGAAmAZ0QBrVAE84wBiQrU6DPAAcATnBv0FQhgG0FAXXGTo8JGiYjEqq6lq6BsamWObsVozMrBYcDDz8qfTkYIY+4H4ygfKIIWoaOvpGJmZslpy2Dk7FiAA+iMQ1Kdx8AlmGXEJiiEPuXogA3oPD2gDuMFAQABZtUIY2qFX2jjwTw7uIEOTaqIgA5L7SYCe0k3t7duggdkibNh2oXOK3QwdHp9pQdhgYGQVxuXyG9ygjyQyVQbhe3kQAHokYgAKIAJQxAHkMYgABKYtFg3aaVDAcggShQehQBYOaaIMCoRlYVaoNF2Bx2YgnBQNVB2FayKDqOyIAC2IH+iAARsd-oDgYg4OLzv4Th8wQBfMTaoA)

Comment: Hm. I mean the implementation signature then becomes a bed of lies, because when prop is a function it won't return the inferred retval of the function. But I suppose that's rather irrelevant since calls get checked against the overload signatures; and since the overload signatures aren't checked against the implementation they're a bed of lies by definition.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get<T, V>(value: T, fn: (value: T) => V): V;
function get<T, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P): T[P];
function get<T, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P | ((value: T) => any)) {
    if (typeof prop === 'function') {
        return prop(value);
    }
    if (prop in value) {
      return value[prop];
    }
    throw new TypeError('Property getter must be string or function');
}

const a = get(1, (a) => a + 1);
const b = get({a: 'a'}, 'a')
console.log(a); // 2
console.log(b);// "a"
```

**Explanation**. There were few problems in the previous implementation:

- return type is already defined in overloads, no need to define it again in the 
  implementation
- checking typeof string automatically creates an intersection with `string` type

The solution is to use `key in object` syntax, this is giving us type specification to `V[P]` and the second branch is checking `typeof function`

---

The exact problem with intersection with string is, that orginal implementation is not able to work with all possible keys types, which are - `number | string | symbol`. For anything other then string as key, the function will throw exception. Consider below example:

```
  // symbol prop example
  const symbolProp = Symbol()
  const v = get({[prop]: 'value'}, prop);
  // array example
  const v2 = get([1, 2], 1);
  // object with number key example
  const v3 = get({1: 'value'}, 1);
```

All three examples will be type correct, but will throw an error, as key is not a string. For the solution I am proposing, all of them will work correctly. The key difference is `prop in value` which ensures that prop is a key of value, but not require specific type of the key.

---

If really we want to ensure that we want only string keys, then the function type definition should be reflecting that. Consider:

```
function get<T, V>(value: T, fn: (value: T) => V): V;
function get<T, P extends keyof T & string>(value: T, prop: P): T[P];
function get<T, P extends keyof T & string>(value: T, prop: P | ((value: T) => any)) {
    switch (typeof prop) {
        case 'function':
            return prop(value);
        case 'string':
            return value[prop];
        default: throw new TypeError('Property getter must be string or function');
    }
}
```

Core difference is - `P extends keyof T & string` we are saying on the type level that we accept only keys of P, which are also strings. That approach is consistent with the implementation where we check `typeof string`.

Comment: I'd suggest making the union signature `function get<T, V, P extends keyof T>(value: T, prop: P | ((value: T) => V))`, but otherwise I do like this answer better than the accepted one.

Comment: Oh I remember, I didn’t go with this one because JS doesn’t throw when you’re accessing a property the object doesn’t have, and leaving properties unset is widely idiomatic. (And JSON can’t roundtrip a property whose value is `undefined`, so using this would break with any data that uses that instead of explicit `null`.) It’s at the hairsplitting level though and you make good points, I just don’t particularly need nonstring keys captured from function parameters very often; although for the sake of correctness I’ll add the constraint.